# checking if a string subset is in column values from a list and assign value in a new column in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have list
procedure_name = [brain, spine, abdomen, thorax]

actual list is longer.

I have a df where one of the columns is ['procedure'] has free text values (as its entered by human operator)

| procedure |
| --- |
| brain and spine |
| BRAIN+SPINE |
| Thorax limited cuts |
| Abdomen contrast |
| Thorax + Abdomen |

and so on..

I want to check if each value in the column has one or more matching terms from the list(procedure_name) and add those terms to new columns ['Anatomy1']['Anatomy2'] ['Anatomy3'] for a max of 3 matches.

Expected output

| procedure | Anatomy1 | Anatomy2 | Anatomy3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| brain and spine | brain | spine | none |
| BRAIN+SPINE | brain | spine | none |
| Thorax limited cuts | thorax | none | none |
| Abdomen contrast | abdomen | none | none |
| Thorax + Abdomen | thorax | abdomen | none |

I tried my best to explain the problem as logically as possible
Thanks in advance

Comment: could you include an expected output from the sample you've provided?

Comment: I have edited to show the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `str.extractall` and a custom regex, then `unstack` and `join`:

```
import re
MAX = 3
procedure_name = ['brain', 'spine', 'abdomen', 'thorax']
regex = '|'.join(procedure_name)

df2 = df.join(df['procedure']
 .str.lower() # optional, to ensure output is lowercase
 .str.extractall(f'({regex})', flags=re.I)[0]
 .unstack('match')
 .reindex(columns=range(MAX)) # optional (see below)
 # alternative to reindex if you
 # don't want to create empty columns
 #.iloc[:, :MAX]
 .rename(columns=lambda x: f'Anatomy{x+1}')
 )
```

Output:

```
             procedure Anatomy1 Anatomy2  Anatomy3
0      brain and spine    brain    spine       NaN
1          BRAIN+SPINE    brain    spine       NaN
2  Thorax limited cuts   thorax      NaN       NaN
3     Abdomen contrast  abdomen      NaN       NaN
4     Thorax + Abdomen   thorax  abdomen       NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Check with `findall`

```
import re
df = df.join(df.procedure.str.findall('|'.join(procedure_name),flags=re.IGNORECASE).apply(pd.Series).reindex(columns = [0,1,2]))
```

Comment: unfortunately it didn't give me the output